# How to avoid cloaking attacks?

Tags: attacks

A few days ago, we found a lot of web pages on Google with the name of our web sites, for example http://website.com/public/our_agency_name.asp.  Every day we find more of this kind of URL.  Looking on the net, this seems to be a cloaking attack.

When we click on one of the URLs, we see a page with a lot of keywords and our agency name.

How is this done?  Where is the problem?  How can this be solved?

Comment: Why do you call it a "cloaking attack" and not just rogue SEO riding on your site reputation?

Comment: becouse i'm a newbie and i don't know well what's happening :D

Comment: should be emphasized that the links lead to a page louis vuitton counterfeit and not to the page of our agency

Comment: It looks like rogue SEO. Not a security issue per se. You'd likely get better advice on a SEO forum.